# Glassfish 3.1 remote instance cant connect to database

Tags: glassfish

in glassfish 3.1 I have two instance on two ssh node and they work fine in a cluster. I created the third ssh node and add the instances in a cluster. SO the cluster has three instances on three remote ssh node.

Web service running on the third node but web service cant connect to database. I believe the new instances has same connector and configuration, resources as other two since the instance is added into the cluster. So all sharing same cluster config.

I am new in glassfish, please help me out.

Thanks